# "Anova" function refuses to compile in R Knitr?

Tags: r, compiler-errors, knitr, anova

The entirety of my code is running perfectly well. When I try to use Knitr to generate PDF/ HTML I get a error that says

`Error in Anova(mod1, type = "III") : could not find function "Anova"`

Any suggestions on what I can do differently?

```
Relevant code:
library(lsmeans)
library(lme4)
df <- read.csv(file = "file.csv", header = TRUE)

library(lmerTest)
mod1 <- lm(Yield ~ Treatment + Block, data = df)
Anova(mod1, type = "III")
lsm <- lsmeans (mod1, "Treatment")


Full Error:
Loading required package: emmeans
The 'lsmeans' package is now basically a front end for 'emmeans'.
Users are encouraged to switch the rest of the way.
See help('transition') for more information, including how to
convert old 'lsmeans' objects and scripts to work with 'emmeans'.
Loading required package: Matrix


Attaching package: 'lmerTest'

The following object is masked from 'package:lme4':

    lmer

The following object is masked from 'package:stats':

    step

Quitting from lines 12-38 (df_test.Rmd) 
Error in Anova(mod1, type = "III") : could not find function "Anova"
Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

Comment: @neilfws I get another error while running a regular comilations saying
`Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`. I think if I am using Type III errors I can only use Anova

Comment: I think you forgot to include the library which supplies the `Anova` function. Perhaps it is loaded in the console, so it works there, but not in the RMarkdown file. From the arguments it may be `library(car)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `library(car)`. `Anova()` function is from this package!

```
library(car)
library(lsmeans)
library(lme4)
df <- read.csv(file = "file.csv", header = TRUE)

library(lmerTest)
mod1 <- lm(Yield ~ Treatment + Block, data = df)
Anova(mod1, type = "III")
lsm <- lsmeans (mod1, "Treatment")
```

Example mtcars:

````
```{r mtcars}
library(lsmeans)
library(lme4)
library(car)

library(lmerTest)
mod1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)
Anova(mod1, type = "III")
lsm <- lsmeans (mod1, "cyl")
```
````

gives:

```
> Anova(mod1, type = "III")
Anova Table (Type III tests)

Response: mpg
            Sum Sq Df F value  Pr(>F)    
(Intercept)   3430  1   333.7 < 2e-16 ***
cyl            818  1    79.6 6.1e-10 ***
Residuals      308 30                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
> lsm <- lsmeans (mod1, "cyl")
> lsm
  cyl lsmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 6.19   20.1 0.567 30     18.9     21.2

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked great. Out of curiosity..would you know  where to find the ANOVA model variance like in standard SAS/SPSS packages. I am new the to the ls.means world

Comment: Here is the documentation <https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/car/versions/3.0-12/topics/Anova>. If you do not get further. Please post a new question with the desired output.